# Param in constructor of custom component is always undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, observable, custom-component

I have 3 observableArrays in ViewModel;

```
groupedCustomFields: ko.ObservableArray<any> = ko.observableArray([]);
customFieldsForAdvSearch: ko.ObservableArray<any> = ko.observableArray([]);
countries: ko.ObservableArray<Country> = ko.observableArray([]);
```

In constructor of ViewModel I initialized them with data from some API Requests

```
constructor() {
 //some other operations

 this.loadCustomFields();
 this.loadCountries();
}

private loadCustomFieldsForAdvSearch() {
    dataService.Management.getCustomFields()
        .done(response => {
            this.groupedCustomFields(sortBy(new CustomFieldsService().getGroupedFields(response.collection), i => i.displayOrder));
            this.customFieldsForAdvSearch(response.collection
                .filter(l => defaultFields.indexOf(l.name) === -1)
                .map(l => {
                    return {
                        fieldName: l.name,
                        displayName: l.display,
                        displayOrder: l.order,
                        value: ''
                    };
                })
                .sort((x, y) => x.displayOrder - y.displayOrder));
        });
}

private loadCountries() {
    dataService.Management.getCountriesWithStates()
        .done(countries => {
            this.countries(countries);
        });
}
```

This observableArrays I pass to my custom component :

```
<component1 params="{
   customFields: customFieldsForAdvSearch,
   groupedCustomFields: groupedCustomFields,
   countries: countries
   }">
</component1>
```

Problem : In constructor of `component1` `groupedCustomFields` is always undefined even if `customFields` and `countries` are ok.

```
constructor(params: any) {
   this.customFields = params.customFields;
   this.groupedCustomFields = params.groupedCustomFields;//undefined
   this.countries = params.countries;
}
```

Why does this happen? How I should resolve it?

Comment: Looking at the code and the tags, we can assume that this is question regarding knockout right?

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte, yes, I've added tag for it :) Or better to add it to question?

Comment: Hey @demo I just saw that you are missing a comma on your component1 call, right after customFields, I just edited your question, but it could be related with your undefined problem, please check if adding that comma helps

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte, OMG! But this is solution! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: no problem, just added the answer so you can resolve it, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was your code:

```
<component1 params="{
   customFields: customFieldsForAdvSearch
   groupedCustomFields: groupedCustomFields,
   countries: countries
   }">
</component1>
```

You have a missing comma on your component call, just add it and it should work, this is a common issue when you are receiving undefined parameters on your ViewModel

```
<component1 params="{
   customFields: customFieldsForAdvSearch,
   groupedCustomFields: groupedCustomFields,
   countries: countries
   }">
</component1>
```